# Add external extension by using registry

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I use Windows 7(64bit) and repeat steps in [Google Document](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/external_extensions.html).

This is what I added in register.

```
In HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Google\Chrome\Extensions\nbfjanngloflombfddlmkgnambnfhgjc
path="C:\Extension.crx"
version="2.1"
```

But extension isn't install.

Before testing .crx file distribution,

I installed and uninstalled this extension with unpacked files many times by UI(chrome://extensions) for development and tested setting policy by using register. (But I removed all of them now.)

Does it cause any problem?

But when I tested same thing in another clean PC(Windows XP 32bit) nothing is changed, too.

I already checked some common mistakes in [Google Document](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/external_extensions.html) several times, but I can't find any mistakes.

```
- Not specifying the same id/version as the one listed in the .crx
- Key created in the wrong location in the registry
- Registry entry points to the wrong path to the .crx file (or path specified but no filename)
- Permissions problems on a network share
```

Are there other common mistakes I should check to install external extension?

Comment: Sorry. I missed the most important thing in question. My problem is that I repeated steps in google document but chrome extension(.crx) isn't install correctly.

Comment: Can you describe the encountered problem with more details? Eg. What errors do you get? Do you have a link to the `.crx` file?

Comment: I tested with another extension in google sample code. link to .crx file is http://www.printmade.co.kr/oz/stackoverflow/set_page_color.crx and its ID is 'neimbcmoijjaenkkjdbafloafdlgoekb'. I move this .crx file in C:\ and set registry. (See http://www.printmade.co.kr/oz/stackoverflow/registry.png) But extension isn't installed.

Comment: Your path (see screencast of the registry) does not equal `C:\Extension.crx`.

Comment: I change path value but it doesnt work, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The extension-ID cannot be chosen at random.
   I've installed your `.crx` file in Chromium 18 (Linux), and Chrome 18 ([Windows 7 in VirtualBox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9538163/938089?which-version-of-windows-7-should-i-buy-to-run-under-vmware-fusion-for-web-dev)), and the correct extension-ID is: **`lhmigopickaaleaaelbppeabnbdgcdhe`**
2. The version number has to match. In the `manifest.json` file, in the extension, I see `"version": "1.0"`. So, the `version` entry in the registry has to be `1.0`.
3. I was not able to install the extension via the registry using the steps from the Documentation. I've found two right ways to install the extension through the registry. Create a `.reg` file, and paste the text below to install the extension:

**`set_page_color_chrome-extension.reg`** (based on [this file](http://www.printmade.co.kr/oz/stackoverflow/set_page_color.crx), <sup>md5: 10a1b95c249a2481bc88d3d1aead0e33</sup>).

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Google\Chrome\Extensions\lhmigopickaaleaaelbppeabnbdgcdhe]
"version"="1.0"
"path"="C:\\set_page_color.crx"
```

Replace `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` with `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` if you're running in permission trouble, or if you want to install the extension only for the current user.

Comment: I execute set_page_color_chrome-extension.reg, but it isn't installed. I worried about installing and uninstalling several time with extension make something wrong, so I tested with another sample code. But it doesn't work, too. Can you help me for checking what I was wrong?(What I do is in http://www.printmade.co.kr/oz/stackoverflow/Stackoverflow.html)

Comment: @Oz6848 The Extension-ID **before** packing is **not equal** to the `.crx`s extension-ID. Drag the `.crx` file to your browser, in order to discover the extension-ID. Then create the `.reg` file as described in my answer. That has to work, since I've personally tested it.

Comment: @RobW Do you know if it is possible to avoid the user intervation to enable automatically the extension?

Comment: No. The point of requiring user consent is that map malware cannot silently install unwanted extensions.

Answer (score 3):

According to this page - https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/external_extensions - 
it is no longer possible to use the registry method to install locally-hosted .crx files.
in fact, the only allowed extension are those from Google's Extension gallery.

See a quote below from Google's policy page:

```
An extension that's installed automatically is known as an external extension. Google Chrome supports two ways of installing external extensions:

-Using a preferences JSON file (Mac OS X and Linux only)
-Using the Windows registry (Windows only)

Both ways support installing an extension hosted at an update_URL. In the Windows registry, the update_URL must point to the Chrome Web Store where the extension is hosted.
```